# Display text in a textview with calendar

Tags: java, android, python

I have created a calendarview in Android Studio, but i am unable to find a code that will allow me to display a text after clicking on a certain date. For example, the code will allow me to show "3 people going" after i click on a date in the textview. The code should also allow me to program each date to display a certain message. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried extending the calendar view class to add these features you want? Or otherwise find some other calendar library that does this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to make custom message view and show this on calendar date click. its not necessary you have to use library for this, but some calendar libraries have built=in message feature.

Comment: Can you further explain the part about calendar libraries? Because all that i used was CalendarView to add a calendar

Comment: in calendar libraries you will have extra features like manage events, appointments and tasks. You will also easily make changes in library code according to your need . here are some calendar libraries   https://github.com/vatsaldesai92/MyDynamicCalendarLibrary   

https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Comment: Thank you for this. I do not really want to use a custom library, can you tell me how to create custom message view and show this on calendar date click?

Comment: as u made adapter for calendar , just make message view xml and show this when you click date.